# Can we inject a request parameter to a http request in apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpwebrequest

We have an Apache web server which acts as a proxy to a tomcat server.

Our web applications are hosted on the tomcat server and the external urls are mapped to the internal urls in the apache.

The protocol used for communication between apache and tomcat is ajp13.

We are required to send a parameter to the webapplication when the first request from a client  reaches the webapplication i.e. when the login page is requested for.

The external url cannot be modified since it is already in use hence additional http get parameters cannot be specified.

Is it possible to inject a request parameter in apache so that by the time request ends up on tomcat it would have this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a servlet filter that checks if a particular cookie is set.   If not, set the cookie and create a HttpServletRequestWrapper with the injected request parameter.  Pass that wrapped request to chain.doFilter().

Comment: Hi Ericacm, I was trying to look at ways to achieve this without changing webapplication

Comment: In that case you could use mod_rewrite with Apache.

Comment: Thanks eric url rewriting seems to be a workable solution for me...will try this...